# Pass object to SOAPHandler without cast in JAX-WS

Tags: java, spring, soap, jax-ws

I'm searching for a way, on the client side, to pass an object to my SOAPHandler without casting my Port object to a BindingProvider to get at the request context.  Usually you see code like:

```
Map<String,Object> requestContext = ((BindingProvider)port).getRequestContext();
requestContext.put("key", object);
```

Where the code in your handler would look like:

```
public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext context) {
    Boolean isRequest = (Boolean) context.get(MessageContext.MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY);

    if (isRequest) {
        // Do stuff to SOAP header based on "object"
    }
    return true;
}
```

I don't like the cast because I'm using Spring's AOP to wrap the calls from the client-side Port object, and the cast causes it to error.

Comment: Try adding `BindingProvider` to the list of interfaces on the port class.

Comment: This object is a generated class, and in this case is packaged inside another team's .jar.  I cannot alter it.

Comment: Just trying to answer your Q, could you pls give brief details:  What type of info do you want to pass SOAPHandler - business data, config setting, in-memory state?  Are you aware that most devs can avoid low-level programming of SOAPHandler (SAAJ) and just generate code via JAX-WS? Do you have a low-level requirement that leads you to SAAJ?  :-)

Comment: Clarification:  ... SOAPHandler (typically using SAAJ API directly) ...  leads you to SOAPHandler/SAAJ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using a version of spring prior to 2.5.6?  If that is the case, you may just need to upgrade spring.  This [change log](https://src.springframework.org/svn/spring-maintenance/trunk/changelog.txt) shows that they added support for the BindingProvider interface in version 2.5.6.

Comment: Still need to cast, but close enough :).  Ensuring that I'm using Spring 3.1 allows me to cast the proxy generated from JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean.